# Проблема с переключением окон на PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pyqt, qt-designer

У меня возникла проблема при попытке сделать переключение окон на *PyQt5*, код прикреплён ниже.

Идея состоит в следующем: 
у пользователя, нажавшего на кнопку **`"Создать новый файл"`**, появляется новое окно (в коде это — класс `CreateFile`), в котором пользователь пишет имя своего файла, 
затем нажимает на кнопку "`Создать новый файл`", имя этого файла передаётся в глобальную переменную, это окно (`CreateFile`) закрывается.

У меня так сделать не получилось. Это окно просто не появляется, вернее, появляется на несколько секунд и сразу закрывается.

Проблема в том, что я не могу вызвать метод `setupUI` у класса `CreateFile`.

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QFileDialog, QApplication, QWidget)

fileIsActive = False 
newFileName = ""


class CreateFile(QWidget):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(336, 228)
        Form.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 281, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 160, 281, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 120, 281, 21))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 100, 131, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        print(100000)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Создайте новый файл прямо сейчас!"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Создать новый файл"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Введите имя для файла"))


class EditFile(QMainWindow):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        self.data = ""
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(670, 414)
        self.TextEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.TextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 651, 351))
        self.TextEdit.setObjectName("TextEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 10, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 141, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 10, 121, 31))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openFile)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.createNewFile)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.saveFile)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Открыть файл"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Создать новый файл"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Сохранить файл"))

    def createNewFile(self):
        second_form = CreateFile()
        second_form.show()

    def openFile(self):
        try:
            fileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(Form, 'Open file')[0]
            with open(fileName, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
                self.data = file.readlines()
            self.TextEdit.setText("")
            for dt in self.data:
                self.TextEdit.append(dt)
        except: 
            Form.setWindowTitle('Произошла ошибка')


    def saveFile(self):
        try:
            fileName = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(Form, 'Open file')[0]
            fileName += ".txt"
            with open(fileName, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
                for dt in self.data:
                    file.write(dt)
        except:
            Form.setWindowTitle('Произошла ошибка')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = EditFile()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Плохая практика изменять файл созданный в QT Designer.

Я не совсем понял, что за новый файл вы будете создавать прямо сейчас? запросим его имя в в виджет QTextEdit ?

Но как вариант, это может выглядеть так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QFileDialog, QApplication, QWidget)


# fileIsActive = False 
# newFileName = ""

# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!
class CreateFile(object):                            #(QWidget):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(336, 228)
        Form.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 281, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 160, 281, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

# ?        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)

        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 120, 281, 21))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 100, 131, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        print(100000)  # ?

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Создайте новый файл прямо сейчас!"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Создать новый файл"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Введите имя для файла"))


# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!
class EditFile(object):            #(QMainWindow):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        self.data = ""
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(670, 414)
        self.TextEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.TextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 651, 351))
        self.TextEdit.setObjectName("TextEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 10, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 141, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 10, 121, 31))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openFile)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.createNewFile)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.saveFile)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Открыть файл"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Создать новый файл"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Сохранить файл"))


class MyCreateFile(QtWidgets.QWidget, CreateFile):            # +++
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyCreateFile, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self) 


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, EditFile):                   # +++
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)      

    def createNewFile(self):
        ''' Создать новый файл '''

        self.second_form = MyCreateFile()                      # - CreateFile()
        self.second_form.show()


    def openFile(self):
#        try:
        fileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file')[0]
        if fileName:
           text = open(fileName).read()
           self.TextEdit.setText(text) 

#            with open(fileName, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
#                self.data = file.readlines()
#            self.TextEdit.setText("")
#            for dt in self.data:
#                self.TextEdit.append(dt)
#        except: 
#            Form.setWindowTitle('Произошла ошибка')


    def saveFile(self):
#        try:
        fileName = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Open file')[0]
        if fileName:
            with open(fileName, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
                file.write(self.TextEdit.toPlainText())

#            fileName += ".txt"
#            with open(fileName, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
#                for dt in self.data:
#                    file.write(dt)
#        except:
#            Form.setWindowTitle('Произошла ошибка')   


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
#    ui = EditFile()
#    ui.setupUi(Form)
#    Form.show()

    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я также взял на себя смелость и немного улучшил ваш код.

Comment: `Плохая практика изменять файл созданный в QT Designer.` согласен :)

Comment: Спасибо, теперь работает всё так, как надо. 

`Плохая практика изменять файл созданный в QT Designer.`Вы имеете в виду, что всю логику программы нужно было перенести в два новых класса так, как Вы и сделали?

Answer (score 2):

> это окно просто не появляется, вернее, появляется на несколько секунд
>   и сразу закрывается.

Я так понимаю, у вас с этим кодом проблемы:

```
def createNewFile(self):
    second_form = CreateFile()
    second_form.show()
```

Это потому что объект в `second_form` не имеет ссылки к чему либо еще и поэтому после выполнения функции происходит его удаление из стека.

Самый простой вариант -- привязать его, сделав полем класса, что его вызывает:

```
def createNewFile(self):
    self.second_form = CreateFile()
    self.second_form.show()
```

Но я бы рекомендовал переделать класс как `QDialog` и вызывать его модально, т.е. это окно будет поверх всех окон приложения и пока его не закроешь код в `createNewFile` дальше не пойдет:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog

...

class CreateFile(QDialog):

...

    def createNewFile(self):
        second_form = CreateFile()
        second_form.exec()  # Вот это обеспечивает модальность окна
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.